# error: no matching function for call to sort

Tags: c++, arrays

From Matthew H. Austern's STL book, "Block" class for a fixed size array.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
struct Block
{
   // Various typedef's

   // Implementations of begin() and end().

   reference operator[](size_t nIndex)
   {
     return data[nIndex];
   }

   // I added this overloaded operator+
   T* operator+(const size_t nIncrement)
   {
     return (data + nIncrement);
   }

   // I added this overloaded cast operator
   // **Why is this cast operator not being called?**
   operator T*()
   {
     return data;
   }

   T data[N];
};
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
Block<int, 10> tArray; // Populate tArray.

// I want to use std::sort() in the same way as I would
// for a regular array.
sort(tArray, tArray + tArray.size());
```

I get the compiler error:

**error: no matching function for call to sort(Block&, int*)**

Why isn't the compiler aware of the overloaded cast operator?

All of the following compile:

```
sort(tArray + 0, tArray + tArray.size());
sort(static_cast<int*>(tArray), tArray + tArray.size());
sort(tArray.begin(), tArray.end());
```

Obviously, there is something about how overloaded cast operators
work that I am ignorant of. Any ideas?

Thanks.

CONSTRAINTS:

I may not use a C++11 (so no std::array from C++11).
I may not use begin() nor end().

Comment: Cast operators aren't considered when deciding on template arguments. Your code would work if sort was not a template function. Cast operators are not generally a good idea,

Comment: FWIW, there's a `boost::array` that works like the now-standard one.

Comment: As John sais above. Since std::sort is a template function it tries to decide the type for the template from the parameters and doesn't know which to opt for. sort<int*>(tArray, tArray+tArray.size()) should work

Comment: I think the best I can do is: sort<int*>(arr, arr+ size);

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement that you may use `begin()` nor `end()` is problematic.  Sort requires random access iterator; see [Bjarne Stroustrup *The C++ programming language 4<sup>th</sup> edition*](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) and [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Using an explicit cast and pointer artithmic, you should be able to do the following:

For example let *`T`* be `std::string`, let *`N`* be 42, and let *`b`* an initialised `Block<T,N>`:

```
Block<std::string, 42> b;
std::string* begin = (std::string*)b;
std::string* end = begin + 42; // Or if Block has Block.size()
                               // std::string* end = begin + b.size()

std::sort(begin, end);
```

Now *`b`* contains the strings sorted according to [`bool operator<(const std::string&, const std::string&)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/).